# Principle branch of Log

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a point $a\in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, how do we determine the set of all points $z$ for which $Log(az)=Log(a)+Log(z)$
I only know that $Log(a)=ln(|a|)+iArg(a)$, I have no idea how to find the set.

Comment: Think about the equality of two complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You basically select $a,b$ with $ Arg(a)+Arg(b) < 2\pi$ , so that you do not "jump the branch" into another one. Remember that each branch has "width" $2\pi^{-}$. Since $Arg(ab)=[Arg(a)+Arg(b)] Mod(2k \pi) $ ,  the $a,b$ that work are those whose arguments add up to less than $2\pi$.

Comment: Does it depend on how we define the principal argument? If we set $Arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$, then$ Arg(-i) \neq Arg(i)+Arg(-1)$.

Comment: @user335468: Precisely. It depends on your choice of argz, whether Arg(z), the principal branch or some other branch argz.

Comment: So, what are the downvotes about?